# R: Convert PCA score into percentiles and sign of loadings

Tags: r, pca, percentile

I use prcomp to preform a PCA on a dataset containing 24 health variables and other socio-economic variables. The purpose is to get a single health index with I can use for my regression analyses. I use the following code:

```
total_pca <- prcomp(health[,-1], scale. = FALSE, rank. = 1)

data$pca <- total_pca$x

data$PVW <- ecdf(-data$pca)(-data$pca) # Convert into percentile
```

From an article it states: *"All loadings are positive, implying that
larger values of the first principal component represent worse health. The first principal component is then converted into individual percentiles, so that higher values reflect better health. Thus, we can interpret the estimated health parameters as changes in the probability of working due to a percentile increase in the health index."*

My problem is that I get both positive and negative loading, so can I still use the same interpretation as in the article? Or should I reverse the sign of the negative ones? And if so, how do I do that?

Another problem is that I have different waves in my data, but I read somewhere that I cannot subset my data into different datasets given the waves and do separate PCAs for each one - is that correct? And if so, how should I do it then?

A reproducible example of my data is:

```
health <- structure(list(wave = c(1, 2, 4, 5, 1, 5, 5, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 5, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 2), fairpoor = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), adl = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), mental = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), heart = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), blood = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), stroke = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), diabetes = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), lung = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), arthritis = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), cancer = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), backjoint = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), doctor = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), hospital = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), nursinghome = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), bmi = structure(c(32.1, 28.7, 24.7, 23.5, 25.1, 26.3, 22.8, 26.3, 17.2, 32.2, 21.2, 23.6, 28.3, 35.8, 28.3, 28.7, 28.1, 20.4, 23.7, 22.7, 20.4, 25.5, 29.7, 20.3, 20.8, 23.1, 23.3, 26.3, 34.2, 40.6, 24.9, 27.2, 26.4, 23.5, 32.1, 32.8, 26.0, 23.4, 23.7, 22.8), labels = structure(c(-3, -2, -1), .Names = c("Implausible/ suspected wrong", "Refusal", "Don't know")), class = "labelled"), walking = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), sitting = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), chair = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), stairs = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), kneeling = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), arm = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), pullpush = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), lifting = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), coin = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("wave", "fairpoor", "adl", "mental", "heart", "blood", "stroke", "diabetes", "lung", "arthritis", "cancer", "backjoint", "doctor", "hospital", "nursinghome", "bmi", "walking", "sitting", "chair", "stairs", "kneeling", "arm", "pullpush", "lifting", "coin"), row.names = c(323L, 1847L, 3731L, 5973L, 244L, 5914L, 6289L, 3847L, 3804L, 75L, 247L, 212L, 3878L, 1858L, 3994L, 2046L, 3920L, 9459L, 1850L, 4000L, 6072L, 253L, 3826L, 148L, 319L, 1855L, 17L, 1849L, 5683L, 1791L, 2002L, 3744L, 2027L, 219L, 4052L, 3837L, 4008L, 127L, 3906L, 1880L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

A ***biplot*** will give you a better interpretation of *PCA* on your health data.

In your given data `bmi` has higher values in magnitude than all other variables, hence will contribute more to variation in data for the same percentage change.

Therefore, it's always recommended to do a scaling so that each variable gets equal importance. Also you example data seems to have fixed columns (0 for all individuals), therefore removed from analysis.

```
  non_zero_counts <- apply(health, 2, function(x) sum(x != 0))  
  all_zero_col <- which(non_zero_counts == 0)

  # removing columns with all zeroes from PCA
  total_pca <- prcomp(health[,-c(1,all_zero_col)], scale. = TRUE)
```

Coefficients of a principal component gives you an idea on how the principal components are correlated with original variables in analysis.

```
 library(ggbiplot)
 ggbiplot(total_pca) + xlim(-2,2) + ylim(-2,2)
```

[image: PCA biplot]

As you can observe, almost all original variables (except diabetes, lung) are negatively correlated to the PC1. If high scores of conditions/ original variables suggest ***bad health*** then higher PC1 scores are correlated with ***good health***